# Communication between swipe view Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i followed this  article  http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/   to implement swipe view  and it work nice.  So now  i want to add button on Tab1 and when clicked has to send data to Tab2.
    I know there is the issue of using interface but honestly  i don't know how to add it on these codes and work provide am  completely new to the android.
  so far i have tried my best on these  links [Communication between SlidingTabLayout tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588024/communication-between-slidingtablayout-tabs), [How to pass data from one swipe tab to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181264/how-to-pass-data-from-one-swipe-tab-to-another) and [How can I communicate/pass data through different Fragments with Swipe Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104600/how-can-i-communicate-pass-data-through-different-fragments-with-swipe-tab)   but i fail.
 Any one help please to make it work on every stage , i mean from Tab1 ->Mainactivity->Tab2

thanks alot

Here are the codes after i edit the question

Fragment1

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

   public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
 Button send;
@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    send=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.send);
         send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
   // value to be sent to the TabFragment2 on button click
           String value=" My Data";

                }
            });

  return v;
      }

    }
```

Fragment2

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

   public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {

@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);
 //Display value from TabFragment1 
  textview.setText(value);
  }
}
```

Interface class

```
public Interface FragmentCommunication
  {
  public void printMessage(String message);

  }
```

MainActivity

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentCommunication{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
     }
           public void printMessage(String message)
         {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
            }


     }
```

Adapter Class

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;    
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;   
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
   int mNumOfTabs;

  public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

Comment: without any code you may get only -1 instead answer...

Comment: you can use setArguments function to pass bundle data to the fragment

Comment: snachmsm  and  SaravInfern  thanks for respond  i have made an  update on the question

Comment: can you please give me a explanation based on the code above @SaravInfern

Comment: i have added codes yet @snachmsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after posting more code I'm answering:

Implement some `FragmentCommunication` for both your `Fragment`s:

```
//public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment implements FragmentCommunication{
public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment implements FragmentCommunication{

    //public static final String TAG="TabFragment1";
    public static final String TAG="TabFragment2";

    ...

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(getActivity() instanceOf MainActivity)
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).registerFragmentCommunication(
                TAG, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void printMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), TAG+" says: "+message,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

note this line inside `onActivityCreated`:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).registerFragmentCommunication(TAG, this);
```

`this` means implemented `FragmentCommunication`, `TAG` will be unique key/name of `Fragment` and whole method is registration of your interface in `Activity`. so now you have to add `registerFragmentCommunication` method to your `MainActivity` and keep reference to passed interfaces, e.g. in `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, FragmentCommunication> fragmentCommunications =
    new HashMap<String, FragmentCommunication>();
...
public void registerFragmentCommunication(String key, FragmentCommunication fc){
    fragmentCommunications.put(key, fc);
}
```

so now you can access each `FragmentCommunication` of both fragments from your `MainActivity`, e.g by using method like this:

```
public void callFragmentCommunication(String key, String msg){
    if(fragmentCommunications.get(key)!=null)
        fragmentCommunications.get(key).printMessage();
}

callFragmentCommunication(TabFragment1.TAG, "hi!");
callFragmentCommunication(TabFragment2.TAG, "hi!");
```

method is public, so `Fragment`s can call it simply like this:

```
//inside TabFragment1
if(isAdded() && getActivity()!=null && 
    getActivity() instanceOf MainActivity && 
        !getActivity().isFinishing())
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).callFragmentCommunication(
        TabFragment2.TAG, "hi!");
```

this will show `Toast` with text: "TabFragment2 says: hi!", which was called inside `TabFragment1`. now you may pass another kind of data as well :)

there is much more methods like communicating through `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager), [passing `Bundle` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063378/how-to-pass-bundle-from-fragment-to-fragment) where fragments are initialized, additional feedback interfaces (e.g. returning true/false when message was passed) etc. Above is just very simplified way, good luck with improving it! :)

Comment: upvote and/or mark as answer my post if it was useful :) good luck! edit: I've edited my answer with proper map init `HashMap<String, FragmentCommunication>()`